# Find occurrences of an Excel formula with Excel-Dna

Tags: excel, excel-dna

Using Excel-Dna I'd like to search all open workbooks in an Excel instance for the number of occurrences of a particular formula.

My best hunch so far is that I need to XlCall the xlcFormulaFind function as documented [here](http://www.technicana.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=111&Itemid=88):

```
XlCall.TryExcel(XlCall.xlcFormulaFind, out result, "MyFunc", 1, 2, 1);
```

However, I just get an ExcelError returned, and am not sure how to dig deeper.

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the C API to call Excel. You can find the old help file for the macro features here: http://www.xceed.be/Blog.nsf/dx/excel-macro-function-help-file-for-windows-7

An alternative to the C API would be to use the COM Automation interfaces. From an Excel-DNA add-in, you get hold of the root Application object by calling `ExcelDnaUtil.Application`. Then the rest of the API is exactly as from VBA.

It looks like you're using `FORMULA.FIND` macro (`xlcFormulaFind`) correctly, and it worked fine when I tried it in this Excel-DNA command:

```
[ExcelCommand(ShortCut = "^G")] // Ctrl+Shift+G
public static void FindMyFunc()
{
    object found = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFormulaFind, "MyFunc", 1, 2, 1);
    if ((bool)found)
    {
        XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcAlert, "Found It!");
    }
    // else it would have shown a message already
}
```

Note the `xlcFormulaFind` returns a bool indicating whether the text was found or not. If a cell was not found, it shows a message and returns false.

You can't use the function from inside a worksheet function (UDF). If the UDF is not marked as `IsMacroType=true` the call the `XlCall.Excel` will fail (throwing an `XlCallException` or returning a fail code if you use `XlCall.TryExcel`). If you do mark the function as `IsMacrotype=true` the macro call succeeds, but always returns false.

Comment: Hi Govert, thanks for the advice, and moreover thanks for Excel-DNA - it's a great piece of software. I never actually got this to work, but I was very pressed for time so didn't get to explore too far, hopefully I'll get back to it sooner or later. In the end I just changed the workflow of my utility to remove the requirement.